# PHP: Duplicate/Blank values when Inserting image names into the DB

Tags: php

I am currently storing in MySQL database image names for easier way to retrieve the actual images. I am having problems with  the php code I created that stores the names. Duplicate and blank insertions are being made into the DB without my permission.

Is there a way to avoid this issue of duplicate or blank values being inserted when the page refreshed?

[image]

```
<?
$images = explode(',', $_GET['i']);

$path = Configuration::getUploadUrlPath('medium', 'target');


if (is_array($images)) {
    try {
        $objDb = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
        $objDb->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'There was a problem';
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `urlImage` (`image_name`) VALUES ";

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $value[] = "('" . $image . "')"; // collect imagenames
    }

    $sql .= implode(',', $value) . ";"; //build query
    $objDb->query($sql);
}

?>
```

Comment: SQL ... injection! Say: "Thanks only one blank column instead of getting the db exploited". Better fix your code. Also do some basic debugging to find your errors firsthand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reformatted things into what I think should be slightly more readable and more easily separate what's going on in the code.  I also updated your queries to show how you can properly "sanitize" your input.

I still think the process by which you're going about sending the data to the server is wrong, but hopefully this code helps you out a little bit.  I'd also do this more object orientedly.. but I feel that leaves the scope of your question just a little bit =P.  It's kind of like everyone else is saying though, the logic for your code was only off *just slightly*.

As for the duplication thing, look into checking if the file already exists before adding it to the database.

```
<?php
$_GET['i'] = 'file1.png, file2.png, file3.png'; // This is just for testing ;].

$images = retrieve_images();
insert_images_into_database($images);

function retrieve_images()
{
    //As someone else pointed out, you do not want to use GET for this and instead want to use POST. But my goal here is to clean up your code
    //and make it work :].

    $images = explode(',', $_GET['i']);
    return $images;
}

function insert_images_into_database($images)
{
    if(!$images)//There were no images to return
        return false;

    $pdo = get_database_connection();

    foreach($images as $image)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `urlImage` (`image_name`) VALUES ( ? )";
        $prepared = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $prepared->execute(array($image));
    }
}

function get_database_connection()
{
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db = 'test';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
        $pdo->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die('There was a problem');
        }

    return $pdo;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will work on those issues you and the other commentators have made known. One question in regards to the function `get_database_connection()`. I am saving the function inside dbConnect.php and then calling it from the imageupload.php. I am getting this error: `Cannot redeclare get_database_connection() previously declared in dbConnect.php`

Comment: Do a search within dbConnect.php and make sure get_database_connection() isn't declared twice =P.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should be checking for blank names in your `foreach` statement, as such:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if($image!='') {
        $value[] = "('".$image."')"; // collect imagenames
    }
}
```

Secondly, you should look into `header("Location: ...");` to prevent users from refreshing the page.

Thirdly, you could also set a session variable or cookie to prevent a user from uploading the same image twice.

Lastly, if the image names are unique, you can set a [UNIQUE index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on the image name.  Then use `INSERT IGNORE` and that will remove all of your duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to avoid duplicates upon refresh is to re-direct the page after the POST, so just doing `header("Location: {$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']}");` should solve that for you.

To avoid empty entries try `is_array($images) && count($images)`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a session variable and tell it to exit or redirect when session variable is not set.

For example

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['session_name']))
{
   exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should change the following line:

```
if(is_array($images)){
```

to this:

```
if(!empty($images) && is_array($images)){
```

explode() returns an empty array even if no "i" parameter is provided